# Multivariable limit, with parameter $\alpha>1$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck with the following limit

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x^2y^2)^{\alpha}}{x^2y^2-(x-y)^2}$$

where $\alpha>1$. I tried with different paths and it seems that the limit is zero. But when I tried to use the definition, I don't know how to find some bound. Also I tried to use polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and I get the expression

$$r^{4\alpha-2}\frac{(1/4)\sin^2(2\theta)}{(1/4)r^2\sin^2(2\theta)+\sin(2\theta)-1}$$

Here I had problems with the fraction. Any hint?

P.d: I looked for similar questions, but didn't find any like this. Sorry for my english and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist (but the limit is zero along all the lines through the origin). Note that the denominator of $f$ is
$$x^2y^2-(x-y)^2=(xy+x-y)(xy-x+y)$$
and therefore the curve $\gamma$: $y=x/(1-x)$ is not contained into the domain of $f$ (the first factor is zero) and it goes through the origin.

Hint: restrict the function along a curve *near* $\gamma$. For example consider  $y=\frac{x}{1-x}+x^{\beta}$ with $\beta$ sufficiently large:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x^2y^2)^{\alpha}}{(xy+x-y)(xy-x+y)}\sim
\frac{x^{4\alpha}}{(-x^{\beta})(2x^2)}$$
What is the limit of $f$ along this curve as $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful hint!